# How to only show new processes in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, process

Is there any way to make `Activity Monitor` only show new processes? Can you do this in `Terminal` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would sort them by ProcessID, newer processes have a higher PID.(Normally)

> Under Unix, process IDs are usually allocated on a sequential basis, beginning at 0 and rising to a maximum value which varies from system to system. Once this limit is reached, allocation restarts at 300 and again increases.